# JSONException while retrieving elements in JSONArray (from json string)

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am having a JSON string (jsonString):

```
["[{"Name":"name.pdf","ValueDate":"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000"}]"]
```

jsonString is an array and I have to retrieve Name elements from it 
I am using below code:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

System.out.println("jsonString"+ jsonString);
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

JSONArray lineItems = jsonObj.getJSONArray(jsonString);
for (Object o : lineItems) {
    JSONObject jsonLineItem = (JSONObject) o;
    String name = jsonLineItem.getString("Name");
    String valueDate = jsonLineItem.getString("ValueDate");
}
```

But I am getting below error:

> net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["[\"[{\"Name\":\"name.pdf\",\"ValueDate\":\"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000\"}]\"]"] is not a JSONArray.
>       at net.sf.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:2038) ~[json-lib-2.4.jar:na]

Can anybody help me in this?

Update:
I used JSONArray lineItems = JSONArray.fromObject(jsonString);  to come over above error suggested by qxz and used below code to loop through JSONArray

```
JSONArray lineItems = JSONArray.fromObject(listDocToSendJson);  
for (int i = 0; i < lineItems.size(); i++) {
     JSONObject jsonObj = lineItems.getJSONObject(i);
     String name = jsonObj.getString("Name");
     String valueDate = jsonObj.getString("ValueDate");
}
```

or

```
for (Object object : lineItems) {
    JSONObject jsonStr = (JSONObject)JSONSerializer.toJSON(object);
    System.out.println(" name is --"+jsonStr.get("Name"));
    System.out.println(" value is ---"+jsonStr.get("ValueDate"));
}
```

Both are giving errors

1. net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.
2. java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to net.sf.json.JSONObject

Please suggest how I can fix this.

Comment: `jsonObj` is empty, so what are you expecting `jsonObj.getJSONArray(jsonString);` to do?

Comment: Hi cricket_007 ...jsonString has array ...i want to retrieve individual elements from array by converting string to jsonarray..

Comment: You do have an array, but it contains just a string. You have too many quotes. Where did this data come from?

Comment: HI  cricket_007 ...From grail JSonbuilder i am getting json... from grails json string look like this [{"Name":"name.pdf","ValueDate":"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000"}]

Comment: Okay, that looks better. I do not know how you got `["[{...}]"]`

Comment: yeah, at java side i am getting this ["[{\"Name\":\"name.pdf\",\"ValueDate\":\"2016-08-30T22:00:0‌​0+0000\"}]"] but isnt it a valid json and cant be parsed? how to remove ["at beginning and at the end "] and backslashes..

Comment: That's why I asked where the data come from. Somehow you are stringify-ing the JSON. I would think that `[{"Name": "name.pdf", ...}]` is what you want

Comment: from grails i am sending it like                                                                 builder listOfObj.collect { obj ->['Name': obj.name,'ValueDate': obj.valueDate]}                    builderString = builderString.replace("\\", "");
        
    builder(
     builderString
     )                                                                           OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(builder.toString().getBytes());
    os.flush();
def code = urlConn.getResponseCode();                                           and then in java getting it as String

Comment: I do not know Grails, but I think the `[]` around the `'Name':...` is not needed. That is likely the outside bracket, then I am not sure why you are replacing backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to retrieve elements from JSON string looking like this 
["[{\"Name\":\"name.pdf\",\"ValueDate\":\"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000\"}]"]
I used json.jar

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

jsonStringList = jsonStringList.substring(2, jsonStringList.length()-2); //removed brackets and double quotes 
    jsonStringList = jsonStringList.replaceAll("\\\\", ""); //remove extra backslashes
    System.out.println("jsonStringList "+jsonStringList); //valid json //[{"Name":"name.pdf","ValueDate":"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000"}]
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStringList);
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {

              JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
              String name = jsonObj.getString("Name");
              String valueDate = jsonObj.getString("ValueDate");
              System.out.println("Name : "+name + "ValueDate : "+valueDate);
  }
```

Thank you all for great help. :)

Answer (score 0):

To convert a JSON array in a string to a `JSONArray`, use [`JSONArray.fromObject`](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html#fromObject(java.lang.Object)):

```
JSONArray lineItems = JSONArray.fromObject(jsonString); // converts String to JSONArray
for (Object o : lineItems) {
  ...
}
```

[`JSONObject.getJSONArray`](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String)) is for retrieving a given key of a JSON object as an array.

Comment: Hi qxz..thanks...it is throwing error now...net.sf.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or ']' at character 6 of ["[{"Name":"name.pdf","ValueDate":"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000"}]"] ...something wrong in format?

Comment: Take a look at your quotes, and the syntax highlighting in your question. Is it supposed to be an array containing a single string, which is also JSON?

Comment: Hi qxz..many thanks...yeah ..i used this [link]http://jsonlint.com/[link] to validate it and corrected...i am unable to loop through JSONArray...please see my updated question.

Comment: ... try replacing the outer `"` with `'`

Answer (score 0):

`["[{"Name":"name.pdf","ValueDate":"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000"}]"]`
The string does not comply to JSON syntax.
Remove leading `["` and trailing `"]` first then it will be looking like correct JSON array.

Comment: This `[[{"Name":"name.pdf","ValueDate":"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000"}]] ` is valid.

Comment: HI Maxim , Enzokie i have changed my json string and it seems correct now..["[{\"Name\":\"name.pdf\",\"ValueDate\":\"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000\"}]"]  ...I am trying to loop JSONArray by extracting JSONObject but it is giving me classcastException..

Answer (score 0):

This is **not valid**

```
["[{"Name":"name.pdf","ValueDate":"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000"}]"]
```

but this one is **valid**

```
[[{"Name":"name.pdf","ValueDate":"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000"}‌​]]
```

The quote ruins the validy of the String. And inorder to parse it you need to loop twice.

```
    JSONArray lineItems = new JSONArray(listDocToSendJson);  
       for (int i = 0; i < lineItems.size(); i++) {
              JSONArray jsonArr = lineItems.getJSONArray(i);
              for (int x = 0; x < jsonArr.size(); x++) {
                   JSONObject jsonObj = lineItems.getJSONObject(i);
                   String name = jsonObj.getString("Name");
                   String valueDate = jsonObj.getString("ValueDate");
              }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work .. just to add your json string had a problem i have corrected that as well it should as

```
[{"Name":"name.pdf","ValueDate":"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000"}]

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONTest {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            String jsonString ="[{\"Name\":\"name.pdf\",\"ValueDate\":\"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000\"}]";

            System.out.println("jsonString" + jsonString);
            try {
                  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                  for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = jsonObj.getString("Name");
                        String valueDate = jsonObj.getString("ValueDate");
                        System.out.println("Name : "+name + "ValueDate : "+valueDate);
            }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi mhasan..which library is this? I am using net.sf.json.JSONArray

Comment: I used the json.jar for this.

Comment: I would prefer using the org.json.* package is more preferred one, you can download from below link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211

Comment: your code works...but for me json string is ["[{\"Name\":\"name.pdf\",\"ValueDate\":\"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000\"}]"] , extra brackets and quotes at begining and at the end, backslashes ..how to remove them all?

Comment: for your reference I did attached the correct format jsonString in my answer, may I know are you receiving this json from UI/HTML via  ajax. if so than you may need to correct it as your json is not parseable syntactically. For your reference again [{"Name":"name.pdf","ValueDate":"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000"}]

Comment: Hi mhasan ..i am getting this from grails client ...i manually removed ["  "] at starting and end of the string so while printing string I am getting this [{\"Name\":\"name.pdf\",\"ValueDate\":\"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000\"}] and now I am getting org.json.JSONException: Missing value at character 2  , how to remove backslashes from it..

Comment: I added backslashed as I hardcoded the jsonString for my example. but you can refer the jsonString which I added at the very top of my answer, which is without backslash                     [{"Name":"name.pdf","ValueDate":"2016-08-30T22:00:00+0000"}]

Comment: Thanks mhasan ..i resolved it with json.jar :)  ..by the way is there any links or online document/sample for this api?